# SQL: Select records where ALL joined records satisfy some condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

How can I write an SQL query that returns a record only if ALL of the associated records in a joined table satisfy some condition.

For example, if A has many B, I want to SELECT * FROM A WHERE all related B's for a given A have B.some_val > value

I know this is probably a pretty basic question, so thanks for any help. Also, if it makes a difference, I'm using postgres.

Sam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming no need for correlation, use:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM A a
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM B b
              HAVING MIN(b.some_val) > a.val)
```

If you do need correlation:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM A a
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM B b
               WHERE b.id = a.id
              HAVING MIN(b.some_val) > a.val)
```

### Explanation

The `EXISTS` evaluates on a boolean, based on the first match - this makes it faster than say using IN, and -- unlike using a JOIN -- will not duplicate rows. The SELECT portion doesn't matter - you can change it to `EXISTS SELECT 1/0 ...` and the query will still work though there's an obvious division by zero error.

The subquery within the `EXISTS` uses the aggregate function MIN to get the smallest B.some_val - if that value is larger than the a.val value, the a.val is smaller than all of the b values. The only need for a `WHERE` clause is for correlation - aggregate functions can only be used in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Just tested, shouldn't need the GROUP BY.  Good solution  (although op says "all related B's" which means there's probably a WHERE clause for b.some_id = a.some_id in the exists).

Comment: This is also probably the most generalized answer, because that HAVING clause could easily be extended.  IE. HAVING a.val = ALL(array_agg(b.some_val)) or the like.

Comment: @OMG: Could you explain what's going on in your answer a little bit?  The use of EXISTS to mean "for all" is blowing my mind.

Comment: @Justin K: Part 1 - The EXISTS evaluates on a boolean, based on the first match - this makes it faster than say using IN, and -- unlike using a JOIN -- will not duplicate rows.  The SELECT portion doesn't matter - you can change it to `EXISTS SELECT 1/0 ...` and the query will still work though there's an obvious division by zero error.

Comment: @Justin K: Part 2: The subquery within the EXISTS uses the aggregate function MIN to get the smallest `B.some_val` - if that value is larger than the `a.val` value, the a.val is smaller than all of the b values.  The only need for a WHERE clause is for correlation - aggregate functions can only be used in the HAVING clause.

Comment: This answer is from almost 13 years ago, I've been developing apps for 20+ years, and I am just now learning this trick.  Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from A
 where -- at least one record in B is greater than some_val
       exists (select null from B
                where B.some_val > :value
                  and A.join_column = B.join_column)
   and -- no records in B are not greater than some_val
       not exists (select null from B
                    where B.some_val <= :value
                      and A.join_column = B.join_column)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.key = b.key AND a.value > b.value
```

Because this does an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) and not a [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins), records from A will only be included if they have records in B that satisfy the condition.

I don't use PostGRE, so I can't guarantee that the syntax is exactly correct.

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.identifier = B.identifier
WHERE
    B.some_val > value
```

You will want to ensure that there is a foreign key from A to B, or some other common identifier.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from a where a.key = b.a_key where b.value > condition
```

Answer (score -1):

Use bookstores and books as an example.

### Bookstore

bookstoreID, bookID

### Book

bookID, price

I suppose you want to return all the bookstores in which all the books have a price greater than X.

```
select *
from Bookstore bs1
where bs1.bookstoreID not exist
 (
  select bs.bookstoreID
  from Bookstore bs, Book b
  where bs.bookID= b.bookID
  b.price < x;   -- your value                                                     
 )
```