# PostgreSQL: query records where ALL joined record attributes match where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I found a similar question but it didn't satisfy my answer: [SQL: Select records where ALL joined records satisfy some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338124/sql-select-records-where-all-joined-records-satisfy-some-condition)

I have two tables, `orders` and `shipments`

`orders` have_many `shipments`

shipments have attribute status `open/closed`

I would like to query orders, where all of its shipments are `closed`:

Assuming table of:

- order1, 2 shipments: 1open, 1closed
- order2, 3 shipments: 1open, 2closed
- order3, 1 shipments: 0open, 1closed
- order4, 2 shipments: 0open, 2closed

Running the query returns records for `order3` and `order4`

I am currently doing this with N+1 using application code, I'd like to just implement in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look for all orders for which there does not exist any shipment (matching that order) with a status other than `closed`.

```
Order.where("NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM shipments WHERE shipments.order_id = orders.id AND status != 'closed')"
```

Comment: Can you explain this? seems too easy

Comment: I tried to (in edit). Basically we're excluding all orders that have any shipment with a status other than 'closed', it is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4306679d33f4e6da62eaa4769e7541d0)

Aggregate the status and then you can filter with the `ALL` operator which checks if all array elements fit the condition.

```
SELECT order_id
FROM (
    SELECT order_id, array_agg(status) status
    FROM shipments
    GROUP BY order_id
) s
WHERE 'closed' = ALL(status)
```

Comment: DBfiddle looks great. but those tables are not matching my tables.

Comment: @BlairAnderson It would be great if you could add your tables to your question. I changed the fiddle and the query. The idea remains the same :)

Comment: [SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7b445ae081c809f07102653b0f69d476) for speed comparison. `NOT EXISTS` is 2.5 faster on average on the 100 data set (the difference will probably grow due to index usage).

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej really nice. Even my second idea `DISTINCT ON` is not as fast as yours. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2a8893ec5f538da7e66fffb293b1d149 Maybe one can tweak a little bit with certain indexes but this depends on the real case.